# Can this integral problem be solved if it involves certain upper and lower limits?

Tags: integration

$\;\displaystyle\int\frac {e^x}x\,dx$

I came to know that this integral does not have a closed form.

> Can't this integral problem be solved even if certain upper and lower limits are involved?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral

Comment: @MyGlasses that question was closed before my edit. So I posted a brief new question after knowing that the solution has no closed form.

Comment: and you want a closed form or estimate result.?